# adding event handlers with jquery independently of knockoutjs bindings

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a `<ul>` element which is populated with a `foreach` binding. This `<ul>` is in turn re-created at different times as the template in which it is embedded is re-rendered. This works fine.

In some cases, however, I would like to add additional behavior to this list (e.g., to log scrolling events) outside of knockoutjs. I don't want this code to be part of the binding because it is only injected conditionally (e.g., when running experiments). I thought I could do something like

```
$('ul.doclist').scroll(function() { 
    // log scrolling here
});
```

after my DOM is initialized, but that doesn't work because `knockoutjs` bindings replace the element to which I am binding the scroll event. Is there an equivalent of a `.live()` for scrolling? Alternatively, is there another way I can dynamically inject my event handler into the knockout binding mechanism that does not rely on the statically-coded attribute?

**EDIT**: 7 Aug 2012 5:41 pm: I tried using the `delegate()` method but cannot figure out how to specify the selector to find my deeply-nested `ul`.

**EDIT**: 7 Aug 2012 6:31 pm: I am using jquery 1.4.4 and testing in Chrome at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up implementing the following pattern:

In my template:

```
<ul class="doclist" data-bind='foreach: rows, event: {scroll: window.viewModel.notifyOfScrollEvent}'>
</ul>
```

in my view model:

```
this.documentScrolled = ko.observable();
this.notifyOfScrollEvent = function() {
    self.documentScrolled.valueHasMutated();
}
```

in my conditional code:

```
viewModel.documentScrolled.subscribe(function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
});
```

Not as de-coupled as I'd like, but better than an explicit reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try delegating event handling to a static container that knockout does not mess with. At the topmost level, the chosen container can be `document`.

`.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7.1 but the same effect can be achieved with `on()`.

```
$(document).on('scroll', 'ul.doclist', function() { 
    // log scrolling here
});
```

With this in place, any `<ul class="doclist">` element will have the logging action regardless of whether it was in place when the handler was attached, or put in place later.

I confess I've never needed to delegate `scroll` but in principle this should work, providing a 'scroll' event actually occurs (*edit - and that it bubbles*).

### EDIT

The following are equivalent :

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Therefore the expression above will translate to:

```
$(document).delegate('ul.doclist', 'scroll', function() { 
    // log scrolling here
});
```

If possible, replace `document` with the selector of more localised container(s).

Comment: I should add that I am stuck using jQuery 1.4.4 at the moment.

Comment: However, I just saw @bmode's answer re. scroll not bubbling, which, on reflection, makes sense - DOH!

Answer (score 1):

From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html), it appears that the "scroll" event does not bubble, so I don't think event delegation will work.

You can use the knockout "afterAdd" and "afterRender" callbacks for the foreach binding (documented in Note 5 on the [foreach documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) to conditionally bind to the scroll event depending on if you want to do the logging or not.

Comment: I guess that means that my knockout code must then know about the logging I am trying to do... I was hoping to keep them separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a delegated registration, choose an element that will always exist (I'll use `body` in the example, but choose the closest one to the target element that you can) and do something like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( 'scroll', 'ul.doclist', handler );
```

For jQuery 1.4.4

```
$( "body" ).delegate( 'ul.doclist', 'scroll', handler );
```

Comment: I should add that I am stuck using jQuery 1.4.4 at the moment.

Comment: I think it should work the same, just using `delegate()` instead of `on()`, and with the different argument order that entails.

Comment: I have not been able to get `delegate()` to work with the `scroll` event at all; @bmode's answer suggests that it doesn't work.